# Chown и chmod для большого количества файлов?

Tags: unix, chmod, chown

Всем привет, на сервере стоит *апач* и куча папок ~ 1 200 000 папок, и в каждой по 1 файлу. Все находится на *Amazon aws*, *linux ubuntu*.

Нужно всем 2 400 000 файлам дать `chown www-data:www-data` и `chmod 0755`.

Я делаю: `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R dir/`.

В итоге проходит минут 15, и удается установить владельца только для 600 000 файлов, а дальше не идет.

Нашел некий `xargs -p` и `find`. Не могу их скомпоновать.

Как установить `chown` только для тех файлов, что сейчас под `root` и так же `chmod 0755` для тех файлов, которые не имеют его.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
find -права -rw-r--r-- dir/ | xargs -p chmod 0755 -R dir/
```

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос решен
[ссылка](https://toster.ru/q/235996)

Answer (score 4):

наиболее быстрый, как мне представляется, вариант — выполнить это одной командой `find` за один проход. примерно так:

```
$ find /путь/ -type f -exec chmod u=rwx,go=rx {} + -exec chown www-data:www-data {} +
```

без каких-либо дополнительных проверок, абсолютно бесполезных в данной ситуации, и лишь занимающих лишнее время.

p.s. кстати, рекомендую не ломать себе голову над значением всех этих загадочных 0755, 1644 и т.п., а пользоваться мнемоническими обозначениями:

- u — пользователь-владелец
- g — группа-владелец
- o — все остальные
- r — право читать
- w — право изменять
- x — право исполнять

пример:

`u=rwx,go=rx` — дать пользователю-владельцу права читать, изменять и исполнять, а группе-владельцу и всем остальным — право читать и исполнять.

можно указывать не только конкретный набор прав, но и изменение прав:

`u+x,o-w` — добавить пользователю-владельцу право исполнять, всех остальных (не пользователя-владельца и не группу-владелеца) — лишить права изменять.

подробнее об этом можно прочитать (если установлена программа `info`) здесь:

```
$ info file permissions
```

Comment: Про мнемонические обозначения очень полезно было узнать.

Answer (score 3):

Простейший вариант выглядит как-то так:

```
find /путь/к/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
```

`find` рекурсивно обходит все внутри указанной папки, `-type f` выводит только файлы, `-print0` выводит найденное с разделителем `\0` (который точно не встречается в путях, в отличие от пробелов и переносов строк) в stdout.

Далее `xargs` читает из stdin список файлов (`-0` задает разделитель), нарезает их на блоки с разумным количеством файлов в каждом блоке, и выполняет `chmod 0755 файл1 файл2 ...`.

Отталкиваясь от этой команды, можно модифицировать ее под ваши нужды, поглядывая на `man`.

Например, `find` может искать по owner'у (`-user`, `-group`), по правам (`-perm` - про синтаксис надо внимательно прочитать в документации).

PS.
1) Вообще я бы наверное сохранил бы список всех файлов, разбил бы его на куски и работал бы по кускам. 2М файлов это как-то очень много.

2) Вообще у find есть опция `-exec`, но я никогда не могу запомнить ее синтаксис, поэтому использую `xargs`

3) А вам точно все эти 2М файлов нужны? Я бы старался не плодить миллионы маленьких файлов - а то будет еще много аналогичных проблем (меня как-то админы ругали за 500k файлов - мол большие у них были при восстановлении).